# Force cellForRowAtIndexPath to be called when numberOfRowsInSection equals to zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I want `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to be always called even if `numberOfRowsInSection` ==0 as i'm hiding and showing a section inside the table by setting `numberOfRowsInSection` to zero but when i do that the method stated above doesn't executed as `numberOfRowsInSection` becomes zero which makes a problem as the contents of the cell remains rendered although the section header disappears, any idea on how to hide the contents of the cell after setting the `numberOfRowsInSection` to zero:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if (section==0||section==1)
    return 1;

if (section==2) {
    if (self.isSectionAppears)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0; 

}

}
```

given that `self.isSectionAppears` is a bool property setted to false when i want to hide the section

Comment: Try reloading the section so it gets redrawn properly with the new number of rows.

Comment: how to reload the section?

Comment: [self.mainTable reloadData]; i already do that on hide/show

Comment: Look at the docs for `UITableView`. There are methods for reloading sections or specific index paths, in addition to the full blown `reloadData`. No need to reload the whole table just to update one section.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be burying your section showing/hiding logic in your cellForRowAtIndexPath. When you need to tell the tableview to update the section header, you can do a refresh on the section with the code

```
NSUInteger sectionToRefresh = //index of table section with header you want to refresh.
NSIndexSet indexSetWithSection = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionToRefresh];
[tableView reloadSections:indexSetWithSection withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

If you'd like to refresh visual elements of your section header without refreshing the rest of the section, you could do so by acting on your section header object directly:

```
//Get section header from table
UITableViewHeaderFooterView* myHeader = [tableView headerViewForSection:sectionToRefresh];

//Update header
[myHeader.textLabel setText:newSectionHeaderText]; //Update it's text for example.
```